# How to configure sbt to load resources when running application?

Tags: scala, sbt

My code (Java) reads an image from jar:

```
Main.class.getResourceAsStream("/res/logo.png")
```

Everything runs fine (if I start the app after packaging it into a jar). But when I run it using sbt's `run` task, it returns me `null` instead of needed stream.

Running this from sbt `console` also gives null:

```
getClass.getResourceAsStream("/res/logo.png")
```

Is there a way to tell sbt to put my resources on classpath?

EDIT:

I set the resources dir to be same as source dir:

```
build.sbt:
resourceDirectory <<= baseDirectory { _ / "src" }
```

When I loaded sbt's `console' and ran the following:

```
classOf[Main].getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource()
```

I got the location of my classes, but it does not contain neither `res` folder nor any of my resource files.

Seems that sbt copies resources only to the resulting jar, and does not copy them to classes dir. Should I modify compile task to move these resources files to classes dir?

EDIT2:

Yes, when I manually copy the resource file to classes dir, I can easily access it from console. So, how should I automate this process?

EDIT3:

It seems that sbt is just unable to see my resource folder - it does not add files to resulting jar file, actually!

Solution:

```
resourceDirectory in Compile <<= baseDirectory { _ / "src" }
```

Comment: I use `getResourceAsStream` from sbt's `run`, `console` and `test` without issue. Maybe some more details would help. What version of sbt? Where is the file located (in another .jar, or `src/main/resources`, or other)? Do you have any resource related plugins or config?

Comment: Sbt - latest version, downloaded today (0.11.2, I think). File is located in src/res/logo.png. And I added "resourceDirectory <<= baseDirectory { _ / "src" }" to build.sbt

Comment: What happens if you follow convention and put the resource in `src/main/resources`?

Comment: @dave - nothing. It still does not work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't give you a full solution right now, but there is a setting called resourceDirectories to which you could add the res folder.

[EDIT]
For me it didn't work also if the resource was in the standard resource folder. Please try it that way:

```
Main.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("icon.png")
```

[EDIT2] This is the full build script (build.scala) which works if your resource is in src/main/java:

```
import sbt._
import Keys._

object TestBuild extends Build {

  lazy val buildSettings = Seq(
    organization := "com.test",
    version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT",
    scalaVersion := "2.9.1"
  )

  lazy val test  = Project(
    id = "test",
    base = file("test"),
    settings = Defaults.defaultSettings ++ Seq(resourceDirectory in Compile <<= javaSource in Compile)
  )
}
```