# How do I use Moxy from Scala?

Tags: scala, sbt, moxy, sbteclipse

This is a follow-on question from [How to un/marshall underscored XML to/from camelcased Java using JAXB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8626394/how-to-un-marshall-underscored-xml-to-from-camelcased-java-using-jaxb)

I'm trying to use Moxy (part of EclipseLink) from Scala (sbt 0.10.0), and am struggling to figure out how to import and use it. To break this into two parts:

**1. Importing Moxy**

For once I can't find anything appropriate on [mvnrepository.com](http://mvnrepository.com). From reading [this page on Maven setup](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Maven), I was hoping the following would work:

```
// /project/Dependencies.scala
object Dependencies {
  val resolutionRepos = Seq(
    ScalaToolsSnapshots,
    "EclipseLink Repo" at "http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?r=1&nf=1&file=/rt/eclipselink/maven.repo"
  )

  object V {
    val moxy      = "2.1.0"
  }

  object Runtime {
    // We use Moxy for the naming convention transforms
    val moxy        = "org.eclipse.persistence"   % "javax.eclipselink"   % V.moxy
  }
```

But sbt is complaining `module not found: org.eclipse.persistence#javax.eclipselink;2.1.0`

**2. Specifying Moxy as my JAXB provider**

With the above fixed (thanks S.R.I.!) the next problem is that I'm having trouble specifying Moxy as my JAXB provider. From the instructions in [this article](http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/05/specifying-eclipselink-moxy-as-your.html) by Blaise Doughan, it looks like I need to put a `jaxb.properties` file with the following entry in the same package as my representations:

```
javax.xml.bind.context.factory=org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory
```

But unfortunately this doesn't seem to be picked up when running through sbt. Any ideas?

Any help gratefully received. And Merry Christmas everybody!

Comment: Did you consider changing your artifactId to `eclipselink` than `javax.eclipselink` ?

Comment: Big thanks S.R.I - that fixed the first problem. I've added a second part to the question as I'm still having questions. Feel free to add a full/partial answer and I will upvote!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**CAVEAT**: I'm not very familiar with SBT syntax

That said, your issue looks like a problem of loading resources from sbt. Normally, you have properties files, images and other related items in the resources folder in your projects(sbt or maven - more since sbt follows maven project structure). Since jaxb.properties needs to be in the same package as your JAXB representation classes, you'll need to configure sbt to look for this in your src folders. Have a look at [this](https://github.com/harrah/xsbt/wiki/Classpaths) page, particularly the section on unmanaged vs managed dependencies.

Alternatively, [this SO page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8588285/how-to-configure-sbt-to-load-resources-when-running-application) talks about the resources problem. Hope this answers your question. :)

---

**EDIT**

Another thing you can consider is, since non source project components are automatically picked up by sbt from the `resources` folder - you can simply place your jaxb.properties in the `resources` directory replicating the path as in `src` folders. For example, if your JAXB representation lies in the package `com.foo.bar.baz` in the `src` directory, you could replicate the structure in `resources` as in `src/main/resources/com/foo/bar/baz` and place your properties file there. I believe it would be loaded into classpath by `sbt`.

Comment: Thanks SRI - I went with your option 2!